# Unable to understand hana regular expression

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hana

Hi I all I am new to Hana and I have a job to convert Hana SQL script to snowflake but I am not able to understand the following thing `\b(?!substring|substr|left|right)[a-z_]+\b` given in regular expression. I did a couple of reading but substr,left and right are methods but here it doesn't look like a method. Below is the code

```
SELECT REPLACE(
            REPLACE_REGEXPR(
                            '("[a-z_]+?"|\b(?!substring|substr|left|right)[a-z_]+\b)' FLAG 'imU' IN :WORDS WITH '__PREFIX__\1' OCCURRENCE ALL),
                            '__PREFIX__', :p_alias||'.') 
                            INTO WORDS FROM SYS.DUMMY;
```

Comment: Ok, and what specifically is the question? The `REPLACE_REGEXPR` function replaces patterns of text. This specific regular expression seems to look for some SQL function names (`SUBSTRING`, `SUBSTR`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`) and replaces thoses with `__PREFIX__<function name>`.

Comment: I want to understand this part !substring|substr|left|right, what is for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

JGNI's answer was clearly correct; I initially overlooked the negative lookahead. The updated answer contains the corrected explanation of the replacement rules.

---

As mentioned in my comment, this `REPLACE_REGEXPR` command looks for different keywords (i.e. `SUBSTRING`, `SUBSTR`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`)  and, for any words that are **not** those keywords replaces it with `__PREFIX__` + the found non-keyword.

So if the input string would look like this:

> SUBSTRING ( **look** left **and** right **before crossing the street** )

The command would find the **bold** marked keywords and return the string

> SUBSTRING ( **__PREFIX__look** left **__PREFIX__and** right **__PREFIX__before** **__PREFIX__crossing** **__PREFIX__the**
> **__PREFIX__street** )

For a live demo check this example at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BjLs7S/1).

So that’s the *what* the command does.
But the OP asked *what it is for*?

Based on the provided snippet of code, this question cannot be answered. Seeing that the command works on some SQL keywords we can speculate that the input string will contain   SQL code and that the purpose of the command is to process this code in some way.

But beyond that - even if it is about SQL code or some other language - the speculations become mere baseless imagination.

The best bet to get an answer to *”what is this for?”* will be to ask the original author of the code.

What I can say with confidence is that this is not a piece of code that is very commonly used in HANA environments. It’s specific custom coding.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Perl compatible regular expressions. The computer language Perl's legacy to computer programming.

You can find out what this does by reading the online Perl documentation for regexs, but in brief:-

```
\b(?!substring|substr|left|right)[a-z_]+\b
```

- \b matches a word boundary, which is defined as the point between a word character and a none word character in either order. Which characters are word characters is predefined by your system, but in general can be thought of as letters numbers and the '_' character
- (?! starts a negative look ahead. Which means that at the current point in the string what appears in the brackets can not appear in the string
- ...|... Is an alternative. So one or the other can match
- [a-z_]+ Is a character class matching a lower case letter in the range a to z. With the `+` means match 1 or more times

Putting this all together we have match a word as long as that word is not substring nor substr nor left nor right